# Odata with no metadata actions not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api-odata

I tried the solution described in this article here:
[Original article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25747525/how-to-hide-metadata-in-web-api-2-odata)

As described i did:

```
var defaultConventions = ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefault();
var conventions = defaultConventions.Except(
        defaultConventions.OfType<MetadataRoutingConvention>());
config.MapODataServiceRoute(
        routeName: "ODataRoute",
        routePrefix: null,
        model: model,
        pathHandler: new DefaultODataPathHandler(),
        routingConventions: conventions);
```

Everything worked ok, no more metadata informations. Standard request work Ok but the unbound actions and functions are not working anymore i get a 404 response.

I register actions to Odata model builder like:

```
var validateEmailAction = builder.Action("ValidateEmail");
        validateEmailAction.Parameter<string>("Email");
```

And in controller i have:

```
[HttpPost]
[ODataRoute("ValidateEmail")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ValidateEmail(ODataActionParameters parameters)
{
}
```

Any suggestions how can i achieve hiding Odatametada but still have actions/functions working?

Comment: did you miss namespace in url or forget to turn on EnableUnqualifiedNameCall?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefault()

will create a list of routing conventions **WITHOUT** attribute routing.

While, unbound actions and functions need attribute routing.

So, You must change to call:

```
ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefaultWithAttributeRouting();
```

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned above ,it works by using default with attribute routing but it also needs config and edm model attributes .

```
var edmModel = builder.GetEdmModel();
var defaultConventions  =ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefaultWithAttributeRouting(config,edmModel);
var conventions = defaultConventions.Except(defaultConventions.OfType<MetadataRoutingConvention>());
        var route = config.MapODataServiceRoute(
            "odata",
            null,
           edmModel,
            pathHandler: new DefaultODataPathHandler(),
            routingConventions: conventions);
```